# IMEI "unknown" on android X86

Tags: android, mobile, imei, android-x86

I have created a virtual machine using Virtual Box that is running android X86. I obtained the .iso image from here http://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-8-1-rc2
I have tried to run my apk and NullPointerException occurs every time when I'm attempting to get the IMEI from the TelephyManger. Here is my code:

```
   final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    String imei = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
```

In the native settings screen I noticed that the serial number is not available (see screen-shot below)
[image]

Does anyone know how to get the IMEI in android X86?

Comment: There is no IMEI. It's an emulator, not a phone.

Comment: Hello @TheWanderer. Thank you for your answer. Do you know if there is a way to fake the IMEI?

Comment: That's illegal.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Ok, thank you again for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @TheWanderer answer the telephony.getDeviceId() is expected to return null.